# Documenting components effectively by Doxygen

Tags: performance, documentation, components, doxygen

**How can you document components of your code such as the following effectively when the source codes of the components are in different locations?**

*Example of my components in my first database project*

```
homepage - user_bar, check_login_status
    ask_question - form_ask_question
    login - form_login
    question_id - (form_login), form_answer, make_answer_list, make_question
```

I read the following command [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#memgroup)

```
/** \addtogroup <label> */
```

However, I am not sure what is the right way of documenting components in source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. components shouldn't be in completely different locations - they should be at least in the same package, namespace, directory, etc. doxygen provides implicit grouping for all those.
2. apart from that, [Module Grouping](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#modules) (the link you mention) is the way to go.